# Update fields in mongoDb document hierarchy dynamically

Tags: mongodb

I am working on updating a collection which has following document structure (2 mentioned as example here):

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "page_id": 1,
    "sec_fields": [
        "title",
        "list"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "title": {
            "content": "How It Works?"
        },
        "list": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "media": {
                        "type": "image",
                        "urls": [
                            "assets/images/book-appointment.jpg"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "media": {
                        "type": "image",
                        "urls": [
                            "assets/images/get-confirmation.jpg"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "media": {
                        "type": "image",
                        "urls": [
                            "assets/images/relax-its-done.jpg"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    "_id": 2,
    "page_id": 2,
    "sec_fields": [
        "social_links"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "social_links": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "media": {
                        "urls": [
                            "assets/images/fb-light-rounded.png"
                        ]
                    },
                    "title": "fb"
                },
                {
                    "media": {
                        "urls": [
                            "assets/images/insta-light-rounded.png"
                        ]
                    },
                    "title": "instagram"
                },
                {
                    "media": {
                        "urls": [
                            "assets/images/yelp-light-rounded.png"
                        ]
                    },
                    "title": "yelp"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Like the two mentioned above there are approximately 50 different document structures. I need to update the `urls` field value using mongodb query. I couldn't find anything in mongodb documentation. Is there a way to update single field from  multiple documents structure ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so my attempt is absolutely crazy and i would not recommend it, but maybe it helps you anyway - I attempted to go by the classic querying -> get data -> modify document -> update document:

```
for key, val in document.items():
    if key == "url":
        print("Do stuff if you want, you can do this on every level")

    if isinstance(val, dict):
        for sub_key, sub_val in document[key].items():
            if sub_key == "url":
                print("Do stuff again")

            if isinstance(sub_val, dict):
                for sub_sub_key, sub_sub_val in document[key][sub_key].items():

                    # so now we have lists.. this only works if the structure is always like this
                    for idx, list_entry in enumerate(sub_sub_val):

                        # check for nested dictionaries again
                        if isinstance(list_entry, dict):

                            for sub_sub_sub_key, sub_sub_sub_val in list_entry.items():

                                # and again
                                if isinstance(sub_sub_sub_val, dict):
                                    
                                    for sub_sub_sub_sub_key, sub_sub_sub_sub_val in list_entry[sub_sub_sub_key].items():
                                        
                                        # now were at the level we want to be at
                                        if sub_sub_sub_sub_key == "urls":

                                            # url paths are again stored in a list, ill just access first index
                                            this_val = document[key][sub_key][sub_sub_key][idx][sub_sub_sub_key][sub_sub_sub_sub_key][0]

                                            print(f"Changing extension from from {this_val} to 'something'")
                                            
                                            # overwrite value
                                            document[key][sub_key][sub_sub_key][idx][sub_sub_sub_key][sub_sub_sub_sub_key][0] = 'something'
```

As you see, i went into 11 indentation levels just to go that 4-time nested dictionary. Didnt find any other option to search for keys inside of nested dictionaries with mixed lists. Good luck though, looking forward for a proper answer :)